# DoS Risk/Vulnerability of a Form calling a client side javascript/webpop

Tags: javascript, forms, security, curl, denial-of-service

I have a simple script that takes the IP entered into a form and launches a web pop/new tab with that IP and a URL after it.  I was wondering how vulnerable to a DoS attack or CURL attack this would be?  Would it be more at risk than say a normal page with video/links ect?  I did a few searches and was unable to come up with an answer specific to javascript input forms.

Thanks for all your help!!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

//alert("Something is Happening!!!") 
window.open("http://"+"IP Address"+"myURL");




</script>


<form name="myform">
    IP Address: <input type='text' name="ipbox2" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { validate(this.value); return false; }">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validate(ipbox2.value)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no different than a user manually entering the IP in the address bar and making a request.

If anything, *you* don't have to worry about the DoS or some other vulnerability, the IP owner is the one receiving the request.

That said. Most webservers don't respond to IP-only HTTP requests, you need the hostname in there.